# When will an EOFException occur in JAVA's streams

Tags: java, input, stream, eofexception

I am working with a DataInputStream and had a question about EOFExceptions.

According to java docs:

> Signals that an end of file or end of
>   stream has been reached unexpectedly
>   during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data
>   input streams to signal end of stream.
>   Note that many other input operations
>   return a special value on end of
>   stream rather than throwing an
>   exception.

Does this mean that when a EOFException is generated, the stream will not NEVER open again? Does it mean you should NEVER expect any more data from it ever?

If an outputstream is connected to an inputstream and outputstream.close() is called, will an inputstream receive the EOFException or an IOException?

An IOException is described as:

> Signals that an I/O exception of some
>   sort has occurred. This class is the
>   general class of exceptions produced
>   by failed or interrupted I/O
>   operations.

Does a close on the outputstream produce either a EOFException or an IOException on the datainputstream side?

Comment: For others' reference: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16513645/691859) explains why `EOFException` gets thrown instead of the methods returning a special value.

Answer (score 7):

The key word is unexpected.

If you use DataInputStream and read a 4 byte integer but there were only 3 bytes remaining in the stream you'll get an EOFException.

But if you call read() at the end of stream you'll just get -1 back and no exception.

Comment: Answer just adds to the confusion. read() returns -1, readLine() returns null, readXXX() for any other X throws EOFException.

Comment: And there is no 'key word' here.

Answer (score 7):

When you reach the end of a stream (end of file, or peer closes the connection):

- `read()` returns -1
- `readLine()` returns null
- `readXXX()` for any other X throws `EOFException`.

The stream is still open, but you should stop reading from it and close it.

Answer (score 4):

Answering another part of your question: Yes, EOF means that no more data will be seen on the stream; you should close it.

Answer (score 3):

EOFException is a subclass of IOException. It will be thrown if you attempt to read from the stream and there is no more data to be read (e.g. because your DataInputStream is wrapped around a FileInputStream and you're trying to read more bytes than are left in the file).

Comment: but how will the datainputstream know that there aren't more bytes coming?  In other words, just because I read and don't see any data doesn't mean the file (in a file input stream) has ended.  It may just be that the bytes haven't arrived yet.  I don't see the FileInputStream returning EOF in docs.

Comment: With a file, you know when you've reached the end. The wrapped FileInputStream would throw an EOFException, which is propagated by the DataInputStream to your code.

Comment: @SimonNickerson +1 but your comment is incorrect. FileInputStream does not throw EOFException. Its read() methods return -1. DataInputStream sees that and throws EOFException.

Answer (score 0):

EOFException is thrown:

1. if there is no data in a **STREAM** but you are trying to read...eg read methods of chain streams like DataInputStream, ObjectInputStream, RandomAccessFile throw EOFException if they are trying to read from FileInputStream but the FileInputStream is empty
2. or if the formats are not matching...eg if int is present and you are using readFloat() of DataInputStream

Comment: Point 2 is not correct. Clearly you haven't tried it. What you describe is impossible. There is no format information in a DataInputStream for the stream to test. It would also be irrational to throw EOFException when the stream isn't empty.