# Why is EOFException used mainly by data input streams?

Tags: java, exception, io, stream

From Java API

> public class **EOFException** extends IOException
>
> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached
>   unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is **mainly used by data
>   input streams** to signal end of stream. Note that **many other input
>   operations return a special value** on end of stream rather than
>   throwing an exception.

So why are data input streams so different from other input operations? Why doesn't it return a special value just like other input operations to signal the end of the stream? Because I think exception should only be used on really exceptional cases.

Comment: The exceptions were created to indicate to the system that an error is happening, and many developers use and develop exceptions to detect an event and then go to an other method or to exit to the system

Comment: @Proverbio Yes, that is what exceptions are for. Your comment doesn't add anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An out-of-band return value is required to signal EOS. All the in-band values are used when returning primitives, so there are no out-of-band values available, so it has to be an exception.

Same applies to `ObjectInput.readObject()`. `null` is an in-band value, so it can't be used to signal EOS.

This is different from `InputStream.read()`, which returns either -1 or a *byte* value -128..127. In this case -1 is out of band.

One assumes that `readUTF()` throws `EOFException` for symmetry with the other methods, although it could probably have returned null at EOS.

Comment: OK, I understand generally. Btw, it is stated in the API that InputStream.read() returns int value from 0 to 255. so why do you say it returns byte value from -128 to 127?

Comment: It returns an `int` which is either -1 for EOS, or 0..255 as a byte value. If you cast that to a `byte`, you get -128..127.