# Why is ObjectInputStream readObject() throwing EOF exception

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream

I am stuck with this very strange problem. In the client I am passing in objects like

```
try{
    oos.writeObject(new GameStartSerializedObject());
    oos.flush();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and in the server I am reading the object

```
try{
    //Its my turn
    thrown_message = player_reader.readObject();
}
catch(Exception e){
```

My question is why am i getting EOF exception. My understanding of object input stream is when i call readObject() i should block until i get an object so how does it know if the eof is reached? Please help!

This is how I create object streams

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.flush();
```

Also, after i write object and flush should i close the stream. I am not closing it since the objects are written pretty regularly from different parts of the code one after another.

Comment: EOFException - Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input. Source (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html)

Comment: but what is causing this end of stream? shouldnt it just block and wait until an object is available.

Comment: I believe there will be an answer to this question shortly. It is my believe, however - if you run the method as you do 'player_reader.readObject();' if object is not available - it will throw this exception. Here is a reference to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664331/when-will-an-eofexception-occur-in-javas-streams

Comment: @e.doroskevic No. Only at end of stream. 'Not available' just causes it to block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peer has closed the connection. Ergo there are no more objects to read. Ergo you have reached the end of the stream. Ergo `readObject()` throws `EOFException.`