# Java EOFException While Reading Object From A Server (not a file)

Tags: java, networking, eofexception

So, I write an object to a client like so:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(args);
out.close();
```

And receive the object on the client side like so:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

Object objIn;
while(true) {
    if((objIn = in.readObject()) != null) {
        //work with obj
    }
}
```

I never create an output stream on the client side or an input stream on the server side.

Also, the object I send is serializable.

Thanks for you help!

EDIT: The "duplicate" of this question doesn't help me answer my problem, so this one is not a duplicate.

Comment: Where exactly you receive the EOF exception ?

Comment: I get the exception when I call in.readObject()

Comment: The duplicate contains exactly the same answer as I have given here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(true) {
    if((objIn = in.readObject()) != null) {
        //work with obj
    }
}
```

Q. Why are you testing for `null`? Are you planning on sending a `null`? Because that's the only time you'll ever get one.
A. Because you think `readObject()` returns `null` at end of stream. Although you've left out the `break` that would escape the infinite loop.

It doesn't. It throws `EOFException.` So your loop should look like this:

```
try
{
    while(true) {
        objIn = in.readObject();
        //work with obj
    }
}
catch (EOFException exc)
{
    // end of stream
}
finally
{
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you received the exception while reading the input stream from connection Object .

If you already invoked the `connection.getInputStream()` prior to the above cited code for input stream you will receive a EOF exception . Because the input Stream in the connection object is already consumed .

[related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913190/why-is-objectinputstream-readobject-throwing-eof-exception)

One solution to such problem is to write the content of the input stream in a Random access file as they enables you to traverse through the file .

```
public static RandomAccessFile toRandomAccessFile(InputStream is, File tempFile) throws IOException
    {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(tempFile, "rwd");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int    tmp    = 0;
        while ((tmp = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            raf.write(buffer, 0, tmp);
        }
        raf.seek(0);
        return raf;
    }
```

Later you can always read from the file as follows .

```
public static InputStream toInputStream(RandomAccessFile file) throws IOException
    {
        file.seek(0);    /// read from the start of the file 
        InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(file.getChannel());
        return inputStream;
    }
```

Comment: Calling `getInputStream()` doesn't consume anything.

Comment: What would I put as the `tempFile` parameter? My program has nothing to do with `File`. The object I send from the servlet is not a `File`. What constructor would I instantiate?

Comment: @LucasBaizer Forget about it, it's pointless.

Comment: The 'related topic' isn't related to your answer in any way.