# ObjectOutputStream Resulting in EOF Error

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to implement object serialization in java. I'm not sure why my code is currently leading to an EOFException, as my code is writing to the file it's supposed to:

Currently, my code is:

```
import java.io.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        product p1 = new product("product", 0, "this is a product.");
        
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("info.dat")));
            out.writeObject(p1);
            out.writeObject(p1);
            System.out.println("Wrote to file");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                            new FileInputStream("info.dat")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    
        
        
    }
}
```

while `product` class is extremely simple, being only:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class product implements Serializable {
    String name;
    double cost;
    String description;
    
    public product(String a,double b,String c) {
        name = a;
        cost = b;
        description = c;
    }
    
}
```

Currently, the output is [image]

Meaning that my code did run and did write to file. I also added an extra write object just in case, so I really don't understand how an EOF error is occurring. Can somebody please explain why?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664331/when-will-an-eofexception-occur-in-javas-streams

Comment: You must close your `out` for changes to be written to disk to the underlying `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @vanOekel could you please explain why this is?

Comment: There are several reasons, but the main one here is that [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close()) calls [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#flush()). In general: always close your `in`/`outputstream`s and do it as soon as possible to avoid trouble.